# What's the easiest way to serve non-blog pages with Blosxom?

Tags: perl, blosxom

I'm using [blosxom](http://blosxom.sourceforge.net/) to serve a blog. I'd like to include a few pages that aren't part of the blog post hierarchy, such as an about page.

For example I'd like to have an about page at `example.com/about.html` that uses the same header and footer as the other pages, but isn't included in the list of recent posts. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

I think it might be possible with the categorization feature, unfortunately the [help page](http://blosxom.sourceforge.net/documentation/users/categorize.html) isn't working.

If it makes a difference, I'm using blosxom to generate the site statically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [static file rendering](http://blosxom.sourceforge.net/documentation/users/configure/static.html) help page.  In the blosxom script itself you should find a configuration setting like this:

```
# Where are this blog's static files to be created?
$static_dir = "/home/bloguser/public_html/bloxsom/static";
```

You can set `$static_dir` to point to the location of the files.

Standard Unix disclaimers regarding ownershipt and permissions for files directories apply.

Comment: `$static_dir` tells where blossom where to put the files it renders. I want to render files that are not blog posts. (undated, no tags, etc.)